# Why are bootstrap grid classes preventing my highchart chart from rendering?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, highcharts

I have a highchart chart that I'm rendering. I am also using bootstrap for the front-end.

My highchart works just fine, as long as I don't have any of the bootstrap grid classes on the chart div.

as soon as I add

```
class="col-sm-7 col-md-7 col-sm-offset-1"
```

to the div, the chart stops rendering.

Test it at:

Working:
https://jsfiddle.net/4pp4ax0v/

Failing:
https://jsfiddle.net/4pp4ax0v/3/

add and remove the class to see the behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Chart is rendering but you can´t see it. The Problem is `min-height`.

Set min-height to 0px then it should work.

```
.col-sm-7, .col-md-7, .col-sm-offset-1 {
  min-height: 0px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/472ey1h5/1/